# ¿Como quitar permiso de una columna en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

estoy queriendo quitar el permiso de una columna de una tabla para un usuario. El problema es el siguiente, vamos a ir paso por paso:

yo creo un usuario

```sql
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

después le doy permiso de execute para poder seleccionar la base de datos:

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE on baseD.tabla to 'usuario'@'%';
```

y le doy permisos de select:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON baseD.tabla to 'usuario'@'%';
```

e intento a proceder quitar permiso para una columna en especifico:

```sql
REVOKE SELECT(campo1) ON baseD.tabla from 'usuario'@'%';
```

El gran problema es que me tira el error de que no tengo tal privilegio. Y es cierto, explicitamente no lo tengo, pero tengo el privilegio total del SELECT.

La única forma que puedo hacer lo que quiero es, dar solamente privilegios a las columnas que quiero que se puedan ver, a excepción de las que quiero "quitar".

La pregunta es... hay alguna forma de dar GRANT SELECT total y luego quitar solamente la que quiero?

Comment: No es posible, al menos en versiones anteriores a la `8.0.16`. La [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) dice esto: *Los privilegios que posee un usuario para una base de datos, tabla, columna o rutina se forman de forma aditiva como el OR lógico de los privilegios de la cuenta en cada uno de los niveles de privilegio, incluido el nivel global. No es posible negar un privilegio otorgado en un nivel superior por la ausencia de ese privilegio en un nivel inferior.* Luego dice que esa norma cambió a partir de MySQL 8.0.16.

Comment: En cualquier caso, ten en cuenta que intentas hacer algo contrario a la lógica y eso puede tener consecuencias, como ralentizar el funcionamiento de la base de datos. Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué no otorgas permisos sobre las columnas específicas únicamente? Es algo que harás una sola vez. Si intentas forzar al manejador (¿quizá por comodidad?) esto podría terminar teniendo un impacto negativo en el rendimiento. Lee las notas de la documentación (enlace precedente).

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por responder!